# Life in a post-scarcity economy

Tags: economy, nanotechnology, post-scarcity, daily-life

Quoting Wikipedia, a post-scarcity is a theoretical economic situation in which most goods can be produced in great abundance with minimal human labor needed, so that they become available to all very cheaply or even freely.

In this scenario, advanced nanofactories have brought about a newfound superabundance of most consumer products, except for food and nanotech itself. These goods are not so abundant that everything is free, but they are available much cheaper and accessible than they would otherwise be.

What are some major differences between the lifestyle of a post-scarcity citizen and an average joe of the present day?

Comment: *"They are available much cheaper"* etc. Could you please explain (and edit the question) under what theory of value you reckon that most goods would be much cheaper? Specifically, the main point is to explain what makes human labor so much more valuable in the fictional world than in the real world. (Because in the end, expensive or cheap are always relative to the median labor wage. Essentially, the question is saying that the average worker can afford to buy with their average income lots more stuff than they can today. Which means that in the fictional world human labor is very valuable.)

Comment: Rats. VTC: This is a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609) and is off-topic. HCQs are open-ended, violate the book rule (too broad), are brainstorming, allow for answers of equal value, are hypothetical.... You get my point. Is there a specific problem stopping your development of a post-scarcity civilization?

Comment: BTW, you didn't include the rest of the quote from Wikipedia. "Post-scarcity does not mean that scarcity has been eliminated for all goods and services, but that all people can easily have their basic survival needs met along with some significant proportion of their desires for goods and services. Writers on the topic often emphasize that some commodities will remain scarce in a post-scarcity society." That's important, because without knowing what economic or resource elements are scarce in your world, we can't answer this question well.

Comment: Everyone would be looking for something to occupy their time, since there would have to be a mandated social minimum wage for all. It would be a pure socialist society, and capitalism would have lost.

Comment: Iain Banks' "Culture" series is the longest treatment of a post-scarcity society that I know about. Since it seems like you have just begun to consider the scenario, you might usefully start your research by taking a look at those books. You can generally read them in any order, so I'd start with _The Player of Games_ as one of the best, and also because it points pretty clearly to the question of value in post-scarcity conditions.

Comment: Agree with JBH, this is a book rule case, it needs (far) more focus to invoke a consise and clear answer.. and the subject seems off topic on WB, it's no fiction, rather real world economics. There may be other SE stacks that have more expertise for this question. Consider splitting it up in several parts and put it on https://economics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

**Poverty**

Goods are available for cheap!  Nanites make them.  Not working people and so these working people are out of jobs.  The people still need food (not made by nanites) and shelter (nanites are poor shelter) but with consumer goods all made by nanites manufacturing jobs have disappeared.  People work service jobs that pay less.  They struggle to make ends meet.  They are downwardly mobile as compared to their parents and grandparents.

It is not so farfetched.  At all.  Manufacturing jobs used to be a staple of first world economies.  Automation taking away jobs was a big deal in the 70s and 80s.  What really took jobs was competitive developing countries where workers are paid less.  Your nanite scenario would be a fine way to explore those issues from a scifi standpoint.   There exist people who get their undies in a bundle at anything that smacks of social commentary.  Maybe such will enjoy your story unawares and go on to think some thoughts they would not otherwise have thunk.  It will be good for them!

Comment: +1 even though I voted to close the question. Poverty in a post-scarcity society is very likely. On top of that, I can imagine that class divisions become much worse. Most people see post-scarcity as some kind of utopia that humanity could achieve if it just gave up childish attitudes. I can't imagine a greater horror - especially when unlimited human growth meets the reality that all resources are limited by definition.

Comment: Class division piece is even more interesting than poverty piece and would make for a very interesting fiction.

Comment: Near-universal poverty is a certainty in any post-scarcity that insists that every individual sell something of value in order to earn their keep. This means almost every real-world society is incompatible with post-scarcity. So, whether you base your culture on real-world society and get conflicts, or imagine a new society that is compatible with post-scarcity, you'll end up with something interesting.

Comment: @Tom
 That 'almost' weasel word in 'almost  every' seems to allow you to leave out (weasel out of) some of the most productive, progressive, socially responsible societies in the world.

Comment: I'm not too sure about the lack of food one though. I could see a world where vertical farms and large scale farming operations exist - even in the U.S. now we have high food yield to human ratios due to industrialization and concentration farming, and while the ethics are dubious I wouldn't consider it too far fetched that in the distant future one agricultural worker overseeing a food plant could feed hundreds of thousands of people.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the Communist Dream.

And like the Communist Dream, the reality would be hellish poverty, removal of choice of products and generally miserable.

The only fictional society where this has been portrayed somewhat realistically is IMO Star Trek (Combination of Matter/Anti-matter power generation and Replicator technology) - however, even in that fictional world, there are items that cannot be replicated and they take on the functional role of Currency (that is, items of value that are traded for other items of Value).

But to answer your question:

Everything would be reduced to it's bare necessity. There's no longer any incentive to compete on making a superior product at a greater price point.
Also, everything would be completely disposable. Why bother trying to repair or mend something when you can pick up a replacement for Free? And so consequently the products would also suffer in quality as this would no longer be a marketable factor.

There would be Food Wars - since people can no longer compete in the productive realm, the only avenue for Status and competition would be those that the nanites cannot make - Food.

People with the capability to control the Nanotech would become the new Oligarchs and de-facto ruling class, very likely that they would enter into a Cartel like alliance with the Farmers - ensuring the Farmers get the tools they need, in exchange for the Food they want.

There would be a massive Black Market for the things that cannot be produces by the Nanotech companies. And there's a number of scenarios around corporate espionage and people trying to acquire Nanotech for themselves (think how 3D printers are eating into certain markets). Speaking of Black Markets...

Prostitution would erupt. Sex is another marketable commodity that cannot be made by the Nanotech robots. In order to get access to the choice cuts of meat and fresh produce (since it cannot be controlled by price) people would resort to Corruption and favors, and Sexual Favors would likely be a significant factor.

There would be a rise in Gang Violence - Young men with nothing to do and no means to differentiate themselves from their peers in order to earn status and so attract a Partner, they will turn to the oldest form of Status known to man: Violence. This would likely be the recruiting ground that the institutions that control the Food Supply would recruit from - the most ruthless and battle-hardened gangers would make excellent Enforcers to make sure that the Food supply isn't 'disrupted'

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141609/discussion-on-answer-by-thedemonlord-life-in-a-post-scarcity-economy).

Answer (score 0):

**Star Trek**

Just to provide the other side of the spectrum from Willk's answer, Star Trek has always represented a post-scarcity environment and it is occasionally discussed in episodes here and there. Star Trek arguably takes it a step further than your idea because *everything* is free, including food, but I suspect your world would get there soon enough:

For example, you didn't make food free (presumably because nanites can't make food) but you've made all farming and processing equipment free, because nanites can make all of that. So global farming should get a major overhaul as even the poorest nations would simply get modern farming equipment for free or close to it. It's possible we'd return to some [ancient forms of taxation](https://historyofyesterday.com/in-ancient-athens-only-the-rich-paid-taxes/), where the rich (presumably, the people who own all these nano-factories) contribute enough on the side to cover a welfare system, which should now be cheap to run. Need a new home? Easy. Food forever? Not much harder, really. Extensive rail system to connect all of Africa with all of Europe and Asia? Give us a minute but we'll get right on it.

For sure you'd have to think about a tremendous upset in what "an economy" even means. Everyone may be free to pursue their own goals, with "social credits" handling their actual needs and most of their wants. If we believe the Star Trek model, it means that everything, including security, is handled by people who want that job (or want the job it leads to if they stick with it and gain experience), because no one really needs or cares about a paycheck. Possibly it really would lead to Star Trek as there would be nothing stopping all scientists from pursuing their interests. Want to investigate highly unlikely sources of energy and propulsion? No problem. Nanite up all the equipment you need. No more scrounging for funding or doing "research that pays" instead of "research I want to do".

And really I think this is the more realistic result. The "haves" would have tremendous incentive to ensure that the world doesn't turn into riots and chaos. They've got it good. Now they just need to keep everyone else happy and if that means figuring out how to make food free, I think they'd do it.

**Where it might get really interesting**, though, is politics and bureaucracy. Nothing stops you from turning your home into a towering structure with 120 floors. The nanites can whip that right up. But you'd still have to convince the Homeowner's Association... (I think Star Trek embodies this well, too. Everything is free, but regulations are forever.)

Comment: I have never seen money change hands in any Star Trek episode, so you seem to be correct.

Comment: *"Need a new home? Easy."* Oh no. The nanites may be able to manufacture cheap bricks, all right; but they cannot possibly manufacture land. The price of a house cannot be less than the price of the land it sits on. *"The rich"* will obviously be the people who own the land, as it was in the Middle Age. (And *Star Trek* is very obviously not a post-scarcity society; throught the story we see that star ships are scarce, and so is everything related to them.)

Comment: @AlexP Yeah I think that's where my last sentence comes in: things may be plentiful, but bureaucracy is plentiful too. Building you a starship in Star Trek isn't the problem. The problem [this never came up that I recall, but seems reasonable] is the years of training, and reams of paperwork, tests, qualifications, etc, required to obtain the government license that says you can have a starship. I figure the same would happen with land. "For The Greater Good." Land barons would end up having their land seized and...  *redistributed*.

Comment: @AlexP
 Once you obtain space travel. land is not an issue. HABITABLE land might be scarce, then again it might not. Seems to me that when they colonized America the powers that be gave the land away for free. It would be interesting what the Doctrine of Discovery would become.

Comment: @ 
AlexP
 A post-scarcity society does not eliminate scarcity. There are always the Laws of Physics that will contribute to scarcity. E=mc^2 kind of thing. There IS a limit, nothing is so infinite that there is not a greater infinite.

Comment: When a society has replicator technology, holodecks, and transporters, making and moving 'things' becomes an energy and data problem. However, you are correct about bureaucracy.In Star Trek, there are reams and reams of rules and regulations on how transporters and replicators are used. One such regulation is that the person must be completely destroyed at the transmision end when the person is replicated at the terminal end. I am sure there would be massive judicial involvement regarding IP rights. Who owns the rights to your replicated (manufactured) body?